# access variables across different classes using kivy

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, class, variables

I am trying to access a variables across classes to compare strings. I thought to use a global but that only works if I assign the global a value. I am assigning each variable random string from a list in one class and then doing the same in another class then comparing to see if they match.

```
class A(screen):
    check1 = ""
    check2 = ""
    check3 = ""

    def on_enter(self):
        rand_files = ["hello", "goodbye", "what"]
        Check1, Check2, Check3 = rand_files

class B(screen):
    Ans1 = ""
    Ans2 = ""
    Ans3 = "" 
    Ans4 = "" 
    Ans5 = "" 
    Ans6 = ""  

    def on_enter(self):
        rand_files = ["hello", "night", "goodbye", "day", "what", "morning"]
        Ans1, Ans2, Ans3, Ans4, Ans5, Ans6 = rand_files

    def verifyAns1(self):
        if Ans1 == Check1 or Ans2 == Check2 or Ans3 == Check3:
            print("You got it!!!")
        else:
            print("Try again")
```

When I try to do it like this I get the error:

```
NameError: name 'Ans1' is not defined
```

Comment: Please make a [mcve] including the full error message.

Comment: It looks like you forgot the `self.` before Ans1-3, but then Check1-3 are undefined.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using class variables in your example. Nothing wrong here, but be aware that if you have multiple instances of these classes, each instance shares the class variables. If one changes a value, the value is changed for all.

If that behavior is not what you are looking for, you probably want to use [Python properties.](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/property)

It is not that one way is necessarily better than the other, it is just how you wish to control the scope of the variables.

That being said, here is an example that may solve your problem using class variables:

```
class A:
    a0 = 0
    a1 = 1
    a2 = 2

    def __init__(self):
        print('hello from A')
        print(A.a0)
        print(B.b2)


class B:
    b0 = 3
    b1 = 4
    b2 = 5

    def __init__(self):
        print('hello from B')
        print(A.a2)
        print(B.b0)


A()
B()
```

And the result:

```
hello from A
0
5
hello from B
2
3
```